# Laravel 7 Select a record if the id dosen't exist in another table

Tags: sql, laravel

Using laravel 7 i am trying to select an item record as long as that records id dosen't appear in another table but only as long as the id in the other table is accompanied by the users id

```
Item table
id
item name


Banned Items
ItemID
UserID
```

Edit 1
If an item is banned it its added to the banned items table that stores the item id and the user id  when i load the items i need to exclude the items that appear in the banned items table but only for the user that is banned for

```
Items table
1 Apple
2 Pear

Banned Items
1 1
1 2

Users
1 username1 password1
2 username2 password2
```

so if the item is banned for that user don't select the item. I'm struggling to do this. Thanks

Comment: Please show some data and make a better explanation based on that data.

Comment: I have added the changed under edit 1

Comment: Could you also add the code that you had tried and is not working ?

Comment: How did you create a relation between banned items and users tables? Is there a user_id column in the banned items table?

Comment: the relationship is handled by me its ItemID because it appears in both tables

Comment: The code was removed because i kept getting the wrong result im now back to my basic select * items i tried using a leftJoin but that didnt work and i tried using a WhereNotIn but that also didnt work because they only worked in specific circumstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand how did you create a relation between banned items and users, but you need that relation. So I assume the columns on banned_items table are

```
id, user_id, item_id
```

```
$bannedItems = BannedItem::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get()->pluck('id');
// If you don't have a model for pivot table:
$bannedItems = DB::table('banned_items')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get()->pluck('id');
$items = Item::whereNotIn('id', $bannedItems)->get();
```

should return the items that weren't banned by the current user.

Comment: Thanks i didnt know you could perform queries like that i assumed it had to be one massive query

Comment: Laravel has a long list of helpers. Documentation helps a lot.